# How Setvalue in FormArray of Element's

Tags: angular

I have form array name `cake`

```
cake: this.formBuilder.array([]),
```

Formarray `cake` is elements's

```
 initCake(c) {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      cakeId: [c._id],
      codeId: [],
      cakelable: [c.cakeNumberLabel],
      cakeChecked: [],
      status: ['normal'],
      action: ['normal']
    });
  }
```

Which output:

```
0: {cakeId: "5bd3f638c77cfe5851828a28", codeId: null, cakelable: "1", cakeChecked: null, status: "normal", …}
1: {cakeId: "5bd3f638c77cfe5851828a29", codeId: null, cakelable: "2", cakeChecked: null, status: "normal", …}
2: {cakeId: "5bd3f638c77cfe5851828a2a", codeId: null, cakelable: "3", cakeChecked: null, status: "normal", …}
3: {cakeId: "5bd3f638c77cfe5851828a2b", codeId: null, cakelable: "4", cakeChecked: null, status: "normal", …}
4: {cakeId: "5bd3f638c77cfe5851828a2c", codeId: null, cakelable: "5", enter code here cakeChecked: null, status: "normal", …}
5: {cakeId: "5bd3f638c77cfe5851828a2d", codeId: null, cakelable: "6", cakeChecked: null, status: "normal", …}
```

How I set value for each array of elements

Example 4 index codeId SetValue like that ...

Comment: Hi, If the problem still persists then suggest you add related HTML code and related TS code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.at(index) method on a formarray: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#at.

That method returns an abstract control where you can call .setValue(value) on.